# how this line works when A Thread(list.add()) and B Thread(list.size()) works?

Tags: java, multithreading

There are two thread, A Thread let the list add ten times, B Thread will quit when the list.size() > 5.I think the result should be "B would quit after A add 5, maybe 6,7,7,8,9",but the result is B never quit.
and the other question is when i add a line there, it would be ok! why?

```
package com.lock;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

/**
 * Create by @author Henry on 2018/5/4
 */
public class NoWait {
    static volatile ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ThreadA a = new ThreadA(list);
        a.setName("A");
        a.start();

        ThreadB b = new ThreadB(list);
        b.setName("B");
        b.start();

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("A is " + a.isAlive());
        System.out.println("B is " + b.isAlive());
    }
}

class ThreadA extends Thread{
    private ArrayList list;
    public ThreadA(ArrayList list){
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                list.add(i);
                System.out.println("=====================================add "+(i+1));
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("A finished");
    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread{
    String s = "";
    private ArrayList list;
    public ThreadB(ArrayList list){
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            while(true){
                //s += list.size();
                //System.out.println(list.size());
                if(list.size() > 5){
                    System.out.println(">5 now, B gonne quit");
                    throw new InterruptedException();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the result is B Thread never stop! this is my first question.

the second is , when I add this line

```
//s += list.size();
//System.out.println(list.size());
```

and it will be ok, Why?!! how they works!

Comment: please add `volatile` rather to the thread classes than in main... (just a guess)

Comment: ...not sure whether `volatile` works at all ... :  [problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+volatile+reference) 
...and ... [solution](https://www.google.com/search?q=atomic+arraylist+java)

Answer (score 2):

Thread B is not guaranteed to see any changes from thread A because there is no synchronization between them.

Volatile won't do anything here as it only ensures the reference to the list is visible to both threads but not updates to its contents.

The println has internal synchronization  which causes the changes between the threads to be visible.

Comment: Thanks!! one last question, why "s+= list.size()" can change the result?

Comment: That line doesn't have any visibility guarantees so I wouldn't expect it to change anything but nothing prevents it from having an effect. It's implementation dependant.

Comment: @henry4real `System.out.println` do the job that you have concern about. System.out.println do have synchorized on its method signature.

Comment: @LiemLe yes, and  s+=list.size() change the result too.